# Android Flash Page in WebView

Tags: android, flash, webview

There is a web page that contains Flash content that I need to load into a WebView. I have tried with these settings:

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

However the flash portion of the site never loads, it just stays a big white space. The same exact site Flash content and all loads perfectly in the stock browser. Is there something I am missing to get WebView to show Flash content?

Edit: Does WebView.refreshPlugins(boolean reloadPages) have anything to do with it? I have tried putting this in various spots but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android 3.0 or greater you may need to add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the `application` (or `activity` depending on where you might have WebViews) attributes in the manifest, I was caught out by this recently.

Comment: Works perfect for Xoom. Do you happen to know any tricks for 2.3 device? On the 2.3 device it is showing me some weird distorted Mobile page instead of the flash content.

Comment: I just grabbed the UserAgent string from the xoom and set it as the UserAgent on the 2.3 device and all is well now. Thanks a ton for your help!